# How to modify an array element and a class member in the same method (Dafny)?

Tags: nat, dafny, correctness

I am coding a simple NAT implementation in Dafny that allows create new mappings and expiring old ones. The method for creating mappings (*translate*) works fine. I am however stuck implementing the *expire* method which is called to remove an old mapping, despite a lot of trying. When calling *expire* from the main method, the compiler complains that

> call may violate context's modifies clause

The problem is that *expire* modifies both the *mappings* field (a map which remembers the association between flow id and the assigned external IP/port), and an element of the *portsAvailable* array which remembers free ports. If I remove any one of these changes, the code compiles but fails to do what I need.

The code for expire method is below (without the annotations):

```
method expire(x:int) modifies {this, this.ports}
{
    ports[portsAvailable] := mappings[x].ext_port;
    portsAvailable := portsAvailable + 1;
    mappings := (map i | i in mappings && i != x :: mappings[i]);
}
```

The full example, including annotations, can be found here: 
https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/9v7K

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Costin